# Wordpress shortcode with a switch

Tags: plugin-development

I am developing a plugin and have a shortcode where some info is added.
this is called by [info]
I would like to be able to add an 'extended' param as a switch so that i can have extended info if i set this
[info] would show short info and [info extended] would show extended with something like

```
   function info($atts){
      extract(shortcode_atts(array(
            'extended' => '',
            ), $atts));
     ob_start();
        echo 'info';
        if (isset($extended)){
            echo 'More info';
            }
      return ob_get_clean();
    }
```

but can not find how to do this. I only find options where i must add value to the param and check this like [info extended="full"] and then check the value of the param.
Anyone got some pointers?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can pass shortcode parameters wihtout values. They just appear on `$atts` with numeric keys. You can see this when you do `var_dump($atts)`. One option to check their existance is then to use `in_array()`.

```
function info( $atts ) {
    // check if extended is passed in $atts with or without value
    $extended = isset( $atts['extended'] ) ? $atts['extended'] : in_array( 'extended', $atts );

    if ( $extended ) {
        // do something
    }

    // more code
}
```